# .NET Core Postgres prevent parallel DB calls

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

.NET Core and Postgres and ADO.NET. I have an API which calls a postgres stored procedure. I have scenario where my API gets called continuously which causes stored procedure execution at same time. What I am expecting is once after the stored procedure called then only next time my stored procedure should be executed. My requirement is stored procedure should not be called same time when same API called.

Here is my API database code:

```
public async Task<bool> ExecuteAsync(bool isChecked)
{
    var connection = await _pSqlHelper.GetConnectionAsync(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DbConnection")!.ToString()).ConfigureAwait(false);

    NpgsqlParameter[] parameters =
             {
                 new NpgsqlParameter("p_checked",DbType.Boolean)
                   {
                        Value = isChecked,
                        Direction=ParameterDirection.Input
                   }
               };

    string commandText = @"call dbo.mysp(:p_checked)";
    var command = await _pSqlHelper.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(connection,commandText,parameters);
    await command.DisposeAsync();
    await connection.CloseAsync();

    return true;
}
```

I want to implement something like when multiple API requests are coming from front end but only once stored procedure executed then only next time it should again. Stored procedure should not be executed same time. Is there any way we can handle this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you want to lock on the ASP.NET side or on the database side? Side note: you are missing `using` on `connection` and `command`, and once you do that you don't need to close/dispose explicitly.

Comment: Hi @Charlieface DB Side. How we can achieve this

Comment: On ASP.NET side you can use a `SemaphoreSlim`, or on Postgres side you could use an Advisory Lock. Depends on requirement, please answer the question.

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface, do you have an example or supporting code block, i would like to have it in database side